# UWP Templete 10 use light theme in designer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, template10

I am developing a UWP app using Template 10 that will be fixed to the light theme. (Sorry, it's a business requirement)

The Visual Studio designer is displaying the app in the default Dark theme. How can I change this so that the designer (not VS) displays the Light theme during design time?

Thank you.

Comment: I can add a RequestedTheme="Light" to each page and this does affect the designer. But is there a way to do this globally? Adding this attribute to the App.xaml has no affect on the designer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to restart VS to see the change in the designer after making changes in the App.xaml

Comment: Welcome :) Happy Developing